# Swagger and openapi-generator-cli deal with inheritence in c#

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, swagger, openapi-generator

I have ASP.NET API written in NET7 with swagger, which generates json for Openapi-generator-cli.

```
openapi-generator-cli generate \
    --type-mappings=DateTime=Date,AnyType=object \
    -i http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json \
    -g typescript-fetch
    -o .\\src\\api-client\\generated
```

In my c# code I have simple hierarchy

```
public class AlertRuleCondition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AlertRuleConditionThreshold : AlertRuleCondition
{
    public decimal Threshold { get; set; }
}
```

My question is what to do pass exactly derived type instead of base type to be proper recognized as derived type by controller in API

```
const formValue: ApiAlertRuleRulesPostRequest = {
  createAlertRuleQuery: {
    //--------------------------------
    // todo: how to force controller in API to recognize conditions as AlertRuleConditionThreshold, NOT as AlertRuleCondition
    conditions: choosenFormAlertRuleCondition as AlertRuleConditionThreshold
    //--------------------------------
  }
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you are generating an `openapi` json from your `ASP.NET API`, and then attempting to use the generated json to generate code using the `typescript-fetch` generator.  In doing this, you are encountering an error in that the polymorphic type generated in the `typescript` code don't match that of the original c# library.  If this is correct, then I suspect there may be an issue with the generated json.  Can you please share the relevant portion of the generated json?